# Row (or column) sums of orthogonal matrix (excluding scalar multiples of identity matrix) always different

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Are row (or column) sums of orthogonal matrix (excluding scalar multiples of identity matrix) always different?

Suppose $Q$ is an $p\times p$ orthogonal matrix that is not a scalar multiple of identity matrix and $\mathbf{1}_p=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ which is a column vector of ones.
Then is $Q\cdot\mathbf{1}_p\neq k\mathbf{1}_p$ always true for arbitary $k$?

If not, is there any counterexample?

I have no clue how to solve this other than the intuition that rotations and reflections are represented by orthogonal matrix so that the statement is likely to be true.

Edit: $Q$ should not be identity matrix $I$.

Edit2: $Q$ should not be  scalar multiples of identity matrix $I$.

Comment: For example, row sums of $Q=I$ the identity matrix are all equal.

Comment: Sorry @peterwhy! I should have excluded the trivial matrix of $I$!

Comment: Or $-I{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: @peterwhy Oh all of those trivial identity matrices should go away!

Comment: For $p=3$, there are three standard basis vectors, all perpendicular to each other and have unit length. Rotate them by the same amount about the axis $\mathbf 1_3=(1,1,1)^T$ to form another orthonormal basis and orthogonal matrix. A [deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4580241/89922) by Salcio also mentioned permutation matrices.